# Retrieve tags from an HTML page to import them into another HTML file

Tags: html, vbscript, tags, copy-paste

**Subject solved! The answer is below.**

Good morning, everyone!
So that's it, I'm telling you my problem. I currently have to create a small script allowing me to retrieve the tags from an HTML file and drop them to another HTML file. I had a possible idea to do this in VBS but without much success for the moment.....
I also thought about doing this with a split but also without much success...

If you have examples of scripts, I'm a taker!
Thank you.

Comment: Example of the wrong attitude for posting on [so]... *"If you have examples of scripts, I'm a taker!"*. Go and read [ask] and think about creating a [mcve] that describes the problem rather than begging for scripts.

Comment: @Lankymart Obviously, you have not seen and/or understood everything. I was provided with a template of scripts that allowed me to get what I wanted through an improvement on my part because not everything was done in the latter and fortunately. Perhaps a lot of reputation on Stack but in terms of understanding you are far from it. And if I asked, it's because I didn't have a basis for the beginning ;)  Sincerely.

Comment: Three close votes suggest otherwise.

Comment: If you wish! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem!
I relied on the code that was provided to me and that was removed and I followed the jQuery doc;)

Doc link: http://api.jquery.com/load/

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    $(function() {
    $("#PremierTest").load("file.html #test1");
    $("#DeuxiemeTest").load("file.html #test2");
    $("#TroisiemeTest").load("file.html #peutetre");
    });
  </script>


<div id="PremierTest">

</div>


<div id="DeuxiemeTest">

</div>

<div id="TroisiemeTest">

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Thank you to all of you :)